# 'curl_version_info_data' has no member named 'libssh_version'

Tags: r, curl, redhat

I need to install **plotly** package for R(3.3.1) in a Redhat server 5.11. It requires **curl** to be installed first. I downloaded the package from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html.

When I try to install the package, it gives below error:

> version.c: In function 'R_curl_version':
>   version.c:15: error: 'curl_version_info_data' has no member named 'libssh_version'
>   version.c:15: error: 'curl_version_info_data' has no member named 'libssh_version'
>   make: *** [version.o] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'curl'

Has anyone had the same issue before?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the development version of the curl library before installing the package. Try `yum install curl-devel`.

One note though - whenever you run into a similar error it is typically because a development version of a library is not installed on your redhat system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jim for your reply.

I found the solution is to use a lower version curl package which has not included the definition for "libssh_version" in the file version.c, e.g. curl_0.9.6.tar.gz with the command:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL curl_0.9.6.tar.gz
```

I've also tried "yum install curl-devel", but it shows the message:

```
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Package curl-devel-7.15.5-17.el5_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package curl-devel-7.15.5-17.el5_9.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```